# Utilizing third party library as a component

Tags: c#, .net, components

I'm trying to utilize a third party library, but it appears they only provide their interface as a component.  It is easy enough to drop it into the form designer and generate the necessary coupling, however I'd like to use the library in a console app or generate a wrapping DLL.

Is there another option besides making a hidden form?

I've tried to add to the dll as a reference, but it displays an yellow triangle and there's a number of conflicting errors (i.e if my object is `XYZ.XYZComponent`. Visual Studio recommends I include a `using XYZ;`. However, I then get an error saying `XYZ` can not be found.)

Comment: Do you have the `dll` for the component. If yes, then add a reference directly to your project.

Comment: What does the library do?

Comment: I feel that this is what happening - you have a dll that references `System.Windows.Forms`. So, try to reference your `XYZ` and also `System.Windows.Forms` to your console app. See if this will make your component visible